# I'm trying to make a batch file that simply opens and saves an xml file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to open an XML file save it without modifying it and then restart a program, right now I have two batch files to do it.

```
notepad.exe "C:\Users\Max Singh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live\Services\Cache\config.xml"
```

Then I manually save in notepad then run the second file,

```
TASKKILL /F /IM sidebar.exe
START sidebar.exe
```

I want to be able to do this in one file without me needing to manually save but I don't know how in a batch file.

Comment: Don't use `/F` with `taskkill.exe` for a non console program which is responding, `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im "sidebar.exe"`. If it is possible that sidebar.exe does not close immediately, then consider putting a small delay in there instead, `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL`. For your main issue, if by saving your file, you simply need to update its file modified timestamp, then you could probably just use `Copy /B "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows Live\Services\Cache\config.xml"+` Then re-start SideBar `Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only reason to open and save the file is to change its modified time, you could try:

```
COPY /y config.xml config.xml.new
RENAME config.xml.new config.xml
TASKKILL /F /IM sidebar.exe
START sidebar.exe
```

Comment: The second command line results in the error message: `A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.` The file `config.xml.new` cannot be renamed to `config.xml` because of `config.xml` still exists in current directory. Inserting as second line `del config.xml` would help to avoid the error on file rename, but copying a file, deleting source file and renaming the copy back to source file does not change the last modification date, just the creation date of the file. There is also no real need to use `taskkill` option `/F` in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is the commonly touted FIX

For a Windows 7 Sidebar is "Hung (non updating)"

Thus needs to be killed and restarted !

I am not certain if this is the best method, however you are the client.
but do read the notes in the comments from others, with more experience.

```
pushd "C:\Users\Max Singh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live\Services\Cache" 
type config.xml > config.tmp
copy /y config.tmp config.xml
del config.tmp
popd

Rem Try the following line either without the /F or change it to /T 
Taskkill /F /IM sidebar.exe
Rem The suggested method is to wait a few seconds so have added 5 seconds 
Timeout 5
start sidebar.exe
```

Note the above is the minimal file for testing and once happy you can add
`@echo off` as your first line

You should add the full paths as per comments to guard against loose cannons that may have a similar name. So the second half should be.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM sidebar.exe
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 5
Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe"
```